# Image Intervention Amazon Cloudfront: Unable to init from given binary data

Tags: laravel-5, amazon-cloudfront

I'm unable to read images being served from Amazon s3/CloudFront with Image Intervention. I keep getting "Unable to init from given binary data"

```
<?php

$image = \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/agentimpress-staging-cdn/img/uploads/agents/1/user-pic.jpg');

$image = \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make('http://cdn.v2.agentimpress.me/img/uploads/agents/1/user-pic.jpg');
```

I thought it might be a permission issue but I'm able to access both images with a web browser. I am also able to use the Image Intervention library to "make" the same image with a local reference. I've also got `allow_url_fopen` turned `On` on both environments I've tested with. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it had something to do with content headers...